# Combining sets of multiple rows in a single Dataframe to generate new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble thinking of a vectorized (or efficient...) solution to a problem involving two large dataframes. One dataframe (df1) is filled with data (floats, ints, and nans). The other (df2) contains a column with n, where n is the number of rows that I want to combine. The index of n matches the index in df1 where the combine should start, grabbing and combining n subsequent rows after it. I.E.:
**Input**

```
mylist = [
    {'1': 'A', '2': 'B','3':'1'},
    {'1': 'C', '2': 'D','3':pd.NA},
    {'1': 'E', '2': 'F','3':'3'},
    {'1': 'G', '2': pd.NA,'3':'4'},
    {'1': 'I', '2': 'J','3':'5'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df1
```

**Output**

```
   1     2     3
0  A     B     1
1  C     D  <NA>
2  E     F     3
3  G  <NA>     4
4  I     J     5
```

**Input**

```
info_list = [{'n':2},{'n':2}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(info_list,index=[0,2])
df2
```

**Ouput**

```
   n
0  2
2  2
```

The index of df2 represents the index in df1 that marks the starting row, and n represents how many total rows I would like to combine into a single row. The resulting dataframe df3 would look like:

**Desired Result**

```
   1  2  3    4     5     6
0  A  B  1    C     D  <NA>
2  E  F  3    G  <NA>     4
4  I  J  5  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I can accomplish with a complicated iterrows() function, but it's slow over the entire dataframe. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the indexes from df2 to indicate where the groupings start.  So index 0, and index 2 are a group, and since the sum of n is 4, any rows after 4 in df1 must be their own group.

Based on that you can number the groups using cumsum, and then creating an incremental value per group which will determine how the rows within the group are split.

Once you have that you can just concatenate the split groups.

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [
    {'1': 'A', '2': 'B','3':'1'},
    {'1': 'C', '2': 'D','3':pd.NA},
    {'1': 'E', '2': 'F','3':'3'},
    {'1': 'G', '2': pd.NA,'3':'4'},
    {'1': 'I', '2': 'J','3':'5'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df1


info_list = [{'n':2},{'n':2}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(info_list,index=[0,2])


df1 = df1.join(df2)
df1.iloc[df2['n'].sum():,df1.columns.get_loc('n')] = 1
df1['n'] = (~df1.n.isnull()).cumsum()
df1['n'] = df1.groupby('n').cumcount()
out = pd.concat([x.drop(columns='n').reset_index(drop='True') for _,x in df1.groupby('n')], axis=1)

print(out)
```

Output

```
   1  2  3    1     2     3
0  A  B  1    C     D  <NA>
1  E  F  3    G  <NA>     4
2  I  J  5  NaN   NaN   NaN
```